# How to prove that every weak solution is classic for a simple parabolic equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

Consider equation
$$
Lu=u_t-a(x)u_{xx}=0, \tag 1
$$
where coefficient $a$ is bounded and $a(x)\ge \delta>0$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$.

If $a$ is not smooth the conjugate operator $L^*$ can not be defined. But equation (1) can be rewritten as 
$$
L_1u=a^{-1}(x)u_t-u_{xx}=0,
$$
which has divergence form. 
So we'll define a weak solution of (1) in domain $Q\subset R^2$ as a continuous function $u$ s.t. for any trial function $\varphi\in C^\infty(Q)$ with compact support in $Q$ the equality 
$$
\int_Q u L_1^*\varphi\,dx\,dt=0
$$
holds, where $L_1^*u=-a^{-1}(x)u_t-u_{xx}$ is the conjugate operator to $L_1$.

Suppose that the coefficient $a$ is regular enough to guarantee that solutions of (1) be classic (i.e. derivatives $u_t$, $u_{xx}$ are continuous), say, let $a$ be from Holder space $C^\alpha(\mathbb R)$, $0<\alpha<1$.

Q: Can it be proved that every weak solution of $(1)$ is a classic solution? Or may be  a question of this sort was considered somewhere?